# What does the following conversation mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I was reading *The Adventures of Tintin* by Hergé. The name of the story was *Flight 714 to Sydney*. This is my first time reading any of Tintin's adventures. In this story, we were introduced to Professor Cuthbert Calculus and Captain Haddock, as well as Tintin himself, and they all traveled to Djakarta.

It seemed that Professor Calculus was somewhat eccentric. Despite Tintin and Haddock repeatedly trying to make the professor understand that they'd just arrived in Djakarta, the professor seemed to not believe them. After landing at the airport, the professor saw a poster that said the following:

> KEMAJORAN (DJAKARTA) INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT

But the professor didn't read the whole thing, and seeing only *Kemajoran*, he started blaming the duo for taking them somewhere besides Djakarta! Then, angry, he said something like the following to them:

> "Always the same, isn't it? 'Poor old Cuthbert, doesn't listen to word you say . . . head in the clouds again . . . always gets the wrong end of the stick!' And on and on and on and on and on!"

I could not connect this part with the rest of their conversation. **What does the quote above, said by the professor, mean?**

Here is the [full rant](http://quizilla.teennick.com/stories/23830196/the-adventures-of-tintin-chapter-3) in its entirety:

> "Hey! Stop! Are you trying to make a fool of me?" yelled Cuthbert. They turned around to see him pointing to a sign that says 'KEMAJORAN (DJAKARTA) INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT.' "There! Look! Kemajoran! Tell me, is this or is this not Djakarta?" said Cuthbert angrily. Haddock turned around and huffed. "Always the same, isn't it? 'Poor old Cuthbert, doesn't listen to a word you say  . . . head in the clouds again . . . always gets the wrong end of the stick.' And on and on and on and on and on!" ranted Cuthbert. They kept walking and heard Haddock mumbling angrily to himself then he tripped over someone's luggage and into a man.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Would you please clearly separate your own question from the passage you're asking about?

Comment: @chrylis, Now I am lost. Clearly I can't understand which part of the question seems hazy to you! I am asking to know the meaning of the conversation the professor said `Always the same.....`. The part of the question before the quotation is context of the question.

Comment: Okay, so this question is your paraphrase of the passage/conversation?

Comment: @chrylis, Yes, my request is to paraphrase, so that I can understand it's meaning clearly.

Comment: Mistu4u: The question is hazy because you have asked about connecting **this part** with **the rest of the conversation** (what exactly is "this part" and "the quoted part"? Do those start with _Always the same_ and end with _on and on and on_? Or do they start with _Poor old Cuthbert_ and end with _wrong end of the the stick_?) Also, the "rest of the conversation" is not really in the question, so it will be hard for us to make that connection as well.

Comment: @snailboat: Thanks for this edit. Actually, I did not know (_and neither was it explained in the comic-book I am reading  from_) that Cuthbert was the middle name of Professor Calculus himself. So I was freaked more thinking where the hell this Cuthbert came from!!

Comment: @J.R., Perhaps **connect** was a poor word choice by me. I just wanted to know the meaning of what Cuthbert (_recently discovered it was the middle name was that very professor_) wanted to say that is quoted by me in the question i.e. `Always the same......on and on`. The part before the quotation was just a context so that you can have some clue on what was the conversation was all about.

Comment: @J.R., I hope I was able to make you understand about my thought process. Still if you think my question lacks understandability, feel free to edit it on your will.

Comment: It seems like your edited question and my answer not far off from each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a crack at this, although I agree with chrylis that it's a little hard to figure out for sure what you are asking.

> "Always the same, isn't it? 'Poor old Cuthbert, doesn't listen to a word you say...head in the clouds again...always gets the wrong end of the stick.' And on and on and on and on and on!" ranted Cuthbert.

Okay, forget about the airport and the context of the story. You have a group of people together, and one of them feels like the others think he's foolish. So he starts a rant:

> Always the same, isn't it?

That means: *No matter what we're doing, you think the same thing of me*.

> 'Poor old Cuthbert, doesn't listen to a word you say...

Cuthbert is talking here, so he is saying what he thinks everyone else is thinking about him: namely, that he doesn't *listen*.

> ...head in the clouds again...always gets the wrong end of the stick.'

means: *Cuthbert doesn't pay attention to what's going on around him; Cuthbert always finds himself confused in life*.

> And on and on and on and on and on!" ranted Cuthbert.

Means that he could keep going with his grumbling rant, if he wanted to, adding things like: *Cuthbert always has his head up his ass, Cuthbert never does anything right, Cuthbert couldn't find his way home if you gave him a map and paid for his taxi fare*, etc.

<sub>If I've not answered your question correctly, let me know, I'll delete my answer.</sub>

Comment: Absolutely meaningful. Two things just to know more about. 1) Who is the person who is talking here? and 2)`head in the clouds again...always gets the wrong end of the stick.` -Is it some kind of proverb or verbal expression understandable by natives only?

Comment: @Mistu4u [Head in the clouds](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/head-in-the-clouds) means you're distracted/not really paying attention. [To get the wrong end of the stick](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/get-the-wrong-end-of-the-stick) refers to misunderstanding the current situation.

Comment: @Mistu4u, It's funny because the things that he is complaining about ("You unfairly perceive me to be distracted, unaware, and misinformed") are in fact exactly true: he is, during this very rant, distracted, unaware, and misinformed.

Comment: @Hellion, Is it? (_I haven't completed the story till now_) But I was falling under the impression that he was somewhat "deaf a little". Because later, too, it was shown in the story that he misheard words and perceived differently.